# pointer to an array of pointers to functions taking int argument and returning void

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

Is the code I have written valid? I am trying to write an expression which is a pointer to an array of pointers to functions which takes a single argument int and return void. So function has return type void. But I am not sure if my expression of `(**[])` is valid or should I write it as `(*(*[]))`? Because the later means array of pointers to a function which is a pointer to a function.

```
void(*(*[])(int));
```

Comment: This is not an expression. Even if you got the syntax right for a type name, a type name is not an expression. It would be helpful to show a bit more context of where you are using this code.

Comment: Are you trying to write a type expression, such as could be used in a cast operator, or are you trying to declare an object *having* such a type?

Comment: TThe website cdecl.org can be very helpful translating between English and C

Comment: http://cdecl.org/?q=declare+aaa+as+pointer+to+array+of+pointer+to+function+%28+arg1+as+int+%29+returning+void

Comment: Ohh. Thanks a lot John for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this

```
 typedef void (*fptr)(int)

 fptr array[10];
```

it's clearer than trying to roll it all into one bit of syntax.